# Building image_view fails on osx

Tags: ros-groovy, image-view, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone succeeded in building image_view on osx?

For me it fails due to:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'image_view'
==> Building with env: '/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/image_view'
==> make -j4 in '/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/image_view'
Linking CXX executable /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/image_saver
Linking CXX executable /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/disparity_view
Linking CXX executable /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/extract_images
[ 12%] Built target disparity_view
[ 25%] Built target image_saver
[ 37%] Built target extract_images
Linking CXX executable /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/image_view
[ 50%] Built target image_view_exe
Scanning dependencies of target image_view
Scanning dependencies of target stereo_view
[ 62%] [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/image_view.dir/src/nodelets/image_nodelet.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/image_view.dir/src/nodelets/disparity_nodelet.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/stereo_view.dir/src/nodes/stereo_view.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/libimage_view.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_signal_connect_data", referenced from:
      image_view::ImageNodelet::onInit() in image_nodelet.cpp.o
      image_view::DisparityNodelet::onInit() in disparity_nodelet.cpp.o
  "_g_type_check_instance_cast", referenced from:
      image_view::ImageNodelet::onInit() in image_nodelet.cpp.o
      image_view::DisparityNodelet::onInit() in disparity_nodelet.cpp.o
  "_gtk_widget_get_type", referenced from:
      image_view::ImageNodelet::onInit() in image_nodelet.cpp.o
      image_view::DisparityNodelet::onInit() in disparity_nodelet.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/libimage_view.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_view.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable /Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/stereo_view
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_signal_connect_data", referenced from:
      StereoView::StereoView(std::string const&) in stereo_view.cpp.o
  "_g_type_check_instance_cast", referenced from:
      StereoView::StereoView(std::string const&) in stereo_view.cpp.o
  "_gtk_widget_get_type", referenced from:
      StereoView::StereoView(std::string const&) in stereo_view.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_view/lib/image_view/stereo_view] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/stereo_view.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

brew list yields:

```
assimp      freetype    libtiff     pkg-config  sqlite
atk     gdbm        libtool     poco        tbb
autoconf    gdk-pixbuf  libusb      postgresql  texi2html
automake    gettext     libyaml     pyqt        tinyxml
boost       gfortran    libzzip     pyqwt       uuid
cairo       glib        log4cxx     pyside      vtk
cmake       gmp     mpfr        python      x264
collada-dom gtest       mysql       python3     xvid
cppunit     gtk+        nmap        qhull       xz
doxygen     jasper      ogre        qt      yaml-cpp
eigen       jpeg        opencv      qwt     yaml-cpp-0.3
faac        lame        ossp-uuid   readline    yasm
ffmpeg      libffi      pango       ruby
fontconfig  libmpc      pcre        shiboken
freeimage   libpng      pixman      sip
```

How can i find out where cmake actually looks for the gtk+ library and fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53155/building-image_view-fails-on-osx/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-23**:
Better question, why is it using gtk+ at all...

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-23**:
What version of image_view are you using (also Mac version, ROS distro, and the output of `brew list`)

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-23**:
Looks like this might be a regression: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/commit/02f8306e310bb8a85d1d7ad4d91c3e7e5ce47608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please test https://github.com/smd-ros-pkg/image_pipeline, and if that makes everyone happy, we can do that. I'm not sure why this is happening, but I think this will get us all compiling for the time being.

Sorry for the regression, there is no way I could have foreseen this happening.

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1